# Can I access Google Secrets Manager secrets externally

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am writing an app that I will be hosting in Google Cloud Functions with some config stored in Secrets Manager. I would like to share this information with another node app that is running on my local machine. Is this possible? I have tried using the npm package but I can’t figure out how I can authenticate to get access to the manager.

I am using a service key to access firestore:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
const service_key = {
    apiKey: myKey,
    authDomain: "my-poroject.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "my-poroject",
    storageBucket: "my-poroject.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "0123456789",
    appId: "0:00000000:web:00000000000000"
 }
const app = initializeApp(service_Key);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

This all works perfectly, but I can't see how I would apply the key or 'app' when using secret manager:

```
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that you have written and the error or stack trace.

Comment: Per @john-hanley, please show your code. You should use [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs) to authenticate your code. Using this, you can access the code off-GCP by creating a Service Account key and exporting the file as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DazWilkin this link starts with the words 'If your application runs inside a Google Cloud environment', my question is explicitly for external apps. Are you implying that this article is misleading and that this solution works equally well internally and externally?

Comment: Yes, see the following section [Passing credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually) where it explains how to do this. You'll probably want to create a Service Account key and reference that as described

Comment: @DazWilkin thans for the clarification. I have now downloaded a service account key, not being sure what access level to assign, I made it project owner and secret manager admin. I then added it as both a system and user level env variable through Windows enviroment manager. I get the following error running the above code: 'Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information'

Comment: Your `SecretManagerServiceClient` code looks correct. When it's running off GCP it will expect to find `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in the environment and I think that's what you think you're doing. The value of the variable is the path to the key **not** the value of the key. Can you check|output the value in your code? `console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);`

Comment: I'm unclear as to your intent with your code. But, if you're using Cloud Functions (these are similar but different to Firebase Functions; I'm less familiar with Firebase Functions), you should be consistent in your use of server SDKs. `@google-cloud/secret-manager` is a server SDK but `firebase/firestore` is a client SDK. The equivalent server SDK is [`@google-cloud/firestore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore). You're using `firebase/app` and so `firebase/firestore` is the companion client SDK. Do you need `firebase/app`?

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks, yes you're correct about the consistency. I started off with the intention of using firestore paired with AWS lambda but then figured I was best keeping everything on the same cloud provider, I will transition to doing everything with the google cloud sdk. My issue ended up being cured by a simple restart. Everything now works as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As public cloud provider, most of the Google Cloud services are publicly accessible. So YES, you can access the secret from outside.

However, you must have the required credentials and permissions to access the secrets.

You can use a [service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating), which is also a secret *(and I never recommend that option, but in some cases, it's useful)*, to generate an access token and to query safely secret manager. The problem is the service account key file, it's a secret to protect secret... The security level depends on your external platform.

You can also have a look to [Identity Federation Pool](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation) that can help you to use your already known identity and to be transparently authenticated on Google Cloud. It's very powerful and you no longer need secret on your side and you increase your security posture.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actuallly already using a key in order to access firestore and since this is desktop software that I have no intention on publishing and so would never leave my machine, I think that a key is probably as good a solution as any. I've added some code to my question, can you please help me understand how I can edit it in order to uuse the key?

Comment: In your code, the "service_key" is the core of the issue. Can you detail its content (at least the pattern, not the detail)

Comment: @guillaume_blaquiere I've updated the question. To clarify though, the key works, I can query and update my firestore collection fine. The problem is, I don't understand how I can use the key to access secret manager.

Comment: Hmm, it's API key based and secret manager isn't compliant with that type of authentication. Service Account can help you to solve that problem but I'm not enough Firebase expert to guide you on that track. On Cloud Functions or other Google Cloud Environment, no problem, but here...